# linux find files in batch

Tags: linux, shell

I have one question: I remotely log in to a linux system. I have bunch of file names which I need to verify if they exist under certain directory (/u02/csv) and sub directories under /u02/csv. I quickly feel exhausted to use find command to search these files one by one. As a brand new bie to linux. Is there any method that I can let linux to read file names from a text file and search these files and output result (for example, if it exist, just list the path, otherwise, just say no) to another file?

B.T.W., this file name list is in my remote PC, could you also suggest how I can put it into linux?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
for line in $(cat files.txt)
do
   find /u02 -type f -name $line >> results.txt
done
```

where `files.txt` lists your filenames, one per line?

Comment: Thank you! :)  Yes, every file name per line. I am sorry for that I may ask a silly question. How can I execute this script? do I need to give script some extension to execute like that in Windows?

Comment: you can do that directly on the command line. otherwise you'll want to read up about [bash programming](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Comment: Note, this will fail if any of the files have spaces in their names.  Also, it's inefficient as it re-opens results.txt on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another sollution:

```
find /u02 -type f -name $(cat files.txt | xargs | sed 's/\W/ -o -name /g') >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean, efficient solution that works with files that include spaces in their name:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
   printf '%s ' "$file"
   if [[ -e "/u02/csv/$file" ]]; then
      printf 'exists.\n'
   else
      printf 'does not exist.\n'
   fi
done < files.txt > results.txt
```